# USACO file missing java

Tags: java

I'm using eclipse to write the program. 
When I try to submit a program, USACO gives me a file missing:

Runtime error or memory limit exceeded on sample input case -- details below
Your output file reorder.out:
[File missing!]

The correct answer:
2 3

The following appeared on standard error:
[File missing!]

It works perfectly fine on my computer, it reads from the input file reorder.in and prints out in reorder.out

you have to create the file reorder.out first to see the file, so it might be the problem.

I'm solving:
USACO 2014 March Contest, Bronze
Problem 1. Reordering the Cows

this is my output code:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("reorder.out")));
out.println(count + " " + max);
System.out.println(count + " " + max);
out.close();
```

if you need more i can add, but i think this is enough.

Comment: Did you see at the bottom of this [page](http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=412) was written _Contest has ended. No further submissions allowed._

Comment: No, i can still submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I found out the answer. Nothing is wrong with my code, you just need to remove all comments for some reason. I copied only my code in another file, only class, name, method, with no comments, TODO, or package headers, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```java
package Cows;
```

for example at the top of your file, you should comment it out. Then it should run properly.

I also had this problem.

**EXAMPLE**

```java
//package Cows;
class Main{
   public static void main(String[] args){
     System.out.println("1");
  }
}
```